# Detect empty row and column with formatting

Tags: excel, vbscript, automation

I am trying to check an Excel sheet for any empty cell using VBScript. I wrote following simple code to detect the number of rows and columns in that spreadsheet and then finding if it is null or not:

```
Set excelWorkbook = CreateObject("Excel.application")
excelWorkbook.Application.WorkBooks.Open("My_Excel_Sheet_Name")
excelWorkbook.Application.Visible = True
WScript.Sleep 2000
Set excelSheet = excelWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
UsedColumns = excelSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
UsedRows = excelSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For columnVariable = 1 to UsedColumns
    For rowVariable = 1 to UsedRows
        if IsEmpty(excelSheet.Cells(rowVariable,ColumnVariable)) Then
            msgbox "Empty cell found at row: " + rowVariable + " column: " + ColumnVariable
        else
            msgbox "Data Found in this cell"
        End if
    Next
Next

Msgbox "Script completed, check logs for more details"
```

This script is working fine as long as there are no empty rows and columns in the end. Where this script is failing:

[image]

I did Ctrl+Shift+End on my Excel sheet and it gave me few extra rows and a column that are formatted but contain no data. I am not able to write code to detect these extra cells.

**Note**: When I checked the value of variable UsedColumns it returned `6` and UsedRows as `4`. So the code is not parsing the last empty rows and columns that are formatted but contain no data, hence my code is failing.

Comment: you can replace you `Used Columns` with `cells(1,columns.Count).end(xltoleft).column` and `UsedRows` with `cells(rows.Count,1).end(xlup).row` however that only relies on the last non empty cell in row 1 and column A, therefore if your data is not consistent, i.e. you have some columns on the right with nothing in top row it will miss them.

Comment: I used: 
`UsedRows = excelSheet.Cells(excelSheet.Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).Row`

It is giving me runtime error on this line:

Unknown runtime error
800A03EC

Comment: I also tried replacing "A" with 1 as you suggested but got same run-time error.

Answer (score 1):

Abandon the [Worksheet.UsedRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx) in favor of the [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx).

```
UsedColumns = excelSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
UsedRows = excelSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
```

The `.CurrentRegion` is the 'island' of data spreading out from the reference cell (`.Cells(1, 1)` in this case) spreading out in all directions until it meets a fully blank row or column.

Comment: Thanks it was useful to know the actual difference between the two. But still it does not solve my problem. Looks like it does not detect formatted rows either. 

I put a top border on blank cells on row 1 and 2 and tried to check the count using 

`UsedColumns = excelSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
UsedRows = excelSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count`

but still the count was same and was showing count of cells containing data only. Looks like it was ignoring the formatting. 

While ctrl + shift + end was able to show that these lines were formatted.